# How do I detect an item with a name in someones inventory for 1.13?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm trying to make a thing where you walk up to it and a gate opens if you have a paper that is named on you but since the 1.13 update I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

The things that have changed since 1.12 are the JSON formatting of custom names, the position of the NBT data of the command and the `/execute` command itself.

Let's say I would like to test if I have a paper on me that is named "Card". Here's what the command would look like:

```
/execute if entity @p[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:paper",tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Card\"}"}}}]}]
```

First of all, I use `/execute if` instead of `/testfor`. Next, I put the NBT into a different position, `@p[nbt={NBT}]` instead of just `@p {NBT}`. Finally, the JSON formatting. Instead of `{Name:"<Name>"}` I used `{Name:"{\"text\":\"<Name>\"}"}`.